# Does ansible allow host based variables syntax?

Tags: ansible

Inventory file allows group based variables:

```
[db]
db1.company.com
db2.company.com

[datacenter-west:children]
db

[datacenter-west:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=ansible_user
ansible_ssh_pass=abcd
```

Does ansible allow host based variables syntax? shown below...

```
[db1.company.com]
ansible_ssh_user=ansible_user
ansible_ssh_pass=abcd
ansible_python_intepreter=/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Does ansible allow host-based variables syntax? shown below..."*

```
[db1.company.com]
ansible_ssh_user=ansible_user
```

A: No. The example is wrong in 3 aspects.

1) `db1.company.com` is not a valid name of a group. [Variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names) should be letters, numbers, and underscores.

2) in [INI](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#adding-ranges-of-hosts) format the brackets start a section with the groups' name or a section with groups' variables. The correct name of a group with one host `db1.company.com` would be for example

```
[db1_company_com]
db1.company.com
```

3) Correct format of a [group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-many-machines-group-variables) would be for example

```
[db1_company_com:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=ansible_user
```

**Correct INI format of host variables**

In INI the host variables are declared in the same line with the host. For example as a standalone host

```
db1.company.com ansible_ssh_user=ansible_user
```

, or a member of a group

```
[db1_company_com]
db1.company.com ansible_ssh_user=ansible_user
```

See details [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-to-build-your-inventory).

Comment: Do you know, what forks mean? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58988863/execution-flow-how-ansible-play-works#comment104680394_58989113)

Comment: I've updated the answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58988863/execution-flow-how-ansible-play-works#comment104680394_58989113).